# angular-translate within nested link

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am trying to apply angular-translate using the 'translate="KEY"' directive.

However, if I add this to a `<p>` tag and then to an `<a>` tag within this, only the first translation appears. When I view this in console, the translation appears to work, but it does not appear on the screen.

```
<p translate="CLICK">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" translate="HERE"></a>
</p>
```

This should output as:
Click [here](http://google.com)

But it appears only as:
Click

Thanks for any help.

Comment: your links aren't working

Comment: If I use the {{ 'KEY' | translate }} it works fine, so I believe the links are ok. I want to use the above way as I can reference the iElement using this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `<p>` surrounds the `<a>` tag. The translate directive replaces the content of `<p>` with the translation. So the result is `<p>Click</p>`.

The directive itself is working fine, see my working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/21ys4WwiWKh4VaomFNGQ?p=preview) .

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950286/angular-translate-within-nested-link" translate="LINK_A"></a>
<a href="http://google.com" translate="LINK_B"></a>
```

-

```
 $translateProvider.translations('en',{
    'LINK_A': 'Stackoverflow',
    'LINK_B': 'Google'
  }).preferredLanguage('en');
```